# Difference between Windows Authentication and SQL Authentication - Views, security, databases

Tags: sql-server

Could somebody explain how you can have different databases/security when connecting in via Windows Authentication from when someone connects via SQL authentication?

I have a customer who had to put a computer onto their network. When they did this, the computer name changed. When connecting into SQL it now has a different server name.

The thing is if I connect using a SQL username and password, I get the databases that were installed before.  However If I connect using windows authentication, I do not get the database.

I would like to know what needs to be changed in order for windows authentication to see the same as a user logging in via SQL authentication.

How can I go about changing the permissions of windows authentication?

Comment: Well… what is the Windows account that you're using to connect to the server as? If it was local to the machine, it may have changed when they connected to network.

Comment: Hi Ben, Yes I believe that this might have occurred. When they connected into there own network the Name of the computer changed. So now when I connect in via Windows authentication its using the new server name and it is more then likely a cause of me needing to give this new login access to the correct database tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within SQL Server, there are Logins (at the server level) and Users (at the database level).  Your SQL Server login obviously has permission to the database(s) you want to see.  The logins can also be windows users and/or groups.  So, if you add a named windows user as a server login, you can extend that login as users in different databases.  You can do the same thing with a group.  So, you could have a single login to your sql server that represents all authenticated users in your domain, etc...

So, I think you need to get into SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and see what logins and users are defined on your SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I believe I fully understand the root cause to this.